# Can't Resolve Data Dependencies in Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, clean-architecture

I am trying to implement clean architecture in my blazor server project. In my application layer I have this service.

```
public class GetOrganizationDetailQuery : IGetOrganizationDetailQuery
{
    private readonly IDatabaseService _database;

    public GetOrganizationDetailQuery(IDatabaseService database) 
    {
        _database = database;
    }

    public OrganizationDetailModel Execute(Guid id)
    {
        var organization = _database.Organizations
                        .Where(x => x.Id == id)
                        .Select(x => new OrganizationDetailModel()
                        {
                            Id = x.Id,
                            Name = x.Name
                        })
                        .Single();
        return organization;
    }
}
```

The interface is also defined in the application project.

```
public interface IDatabaseService
{
    DbSet<Domain.Organization> Organizations { get; }

    void Save();
}
```

My data layer relies on the application layer, and it defines an implementation of the above interface.

```
public class DatabaseService : DbContext, IDatabaseService
{
    ...

    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }

    public void Save()
    {
        this.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Finally in my UI layer I try to inject the query so I can use it on a page.

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGetOrganizationDetailQuery, GetOrganizationDetailQuery>();
```

This throws an exception; the service cannot be constructed.

Is there any way to fix this issue without adding a reference to the data layer from my UI layer?

Comment: `GetOrganizationDetailQuery` is an Infrastructure layer implementation of the contract defined by `IGetOrganizationDetailQuery` in your application layer.  A WASM version of `IGetOrganizationDetailQuery` could call a API service to get the data.  You're interface should only define `Execute`.   See this article which may provide you some pointers, including using request and result objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you need to reference all projects where interfaces and implementations are defined to be able to use dependency injection.

My preference is to move all dependency registration into a dedicated project. This (in my opinion) keeps the app cleaner and means that I can avoid referencing implementation projects (e.g. Entity Framework implementations).

The downside with this approach is that you need to be able to abstract the dependency container itself, but this (again, my opinion) is a worthwhile trade-off.

**Dependency Registrar project**

```cs
// The dependency container abstraction, 
// implemented in the app project. 
// You can add any additional registration functionality 
// that you require.
public interface IDependencyContainer
{
  IDependencyContainer AddScoped<TInterface, TImplementation>()
    where TInterface : class
    where TImplementation : class, TInterface;
}

// The dependency registration itself, 
// called by the app project
public static class DependencyConfig
{
  public static void RegisterDependencies(
    IDependencyContainer container, 
    IConfiguration config)
  {
    container.AddScoped<
      IGetOrganizationDetailQuery, 
      GetOrganizationDetailQuery>();
  }
}
```

**App project**

```cs
// The implementation of the 
// dependency container abstraction.
// Really just a wrapper for the methods
// available on IServiceCollection.
// Requires that you add a reference to the 
// Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions NuGet package
public class DependencyContainer : IDependencyContainer
{
  private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

  public DependencyContainer(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    _services = services;
  }

  public IDependencyContainer AddScoped<TInterface, 
    TImplementation>()
    where TInterface : class
    where TImplementation : class, TInterface
  {
    _services.AddScoped<TInterface, TImplementation>();
    return this;
  }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
// Invoke dependency registration in the Program.cs file
IDependencyContainer container = 
  new DependencyContainer(builder.Services);
DependencyConfig.RegisterDependencies(container, 
  builder.Configuration);
```